# XMLHttpRequest() post does not appear as file on server

Tags: javascript, function, xmlhttprequest

As far as my limited understanding goes, this function should create a file on the server containing the text string returned by the function NewFileToSave():

```
function SaveDay()
{
 var toSend = NewFileToSave();
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open('POST', 'postTest.dat', true);
 xhr.onload = 
  function(e) 
  {
    if (this.status == 200) 
    {
        alert("Sent");
    }
  };
 xhr.send(toSend);
 alert(toSend);
}
```

When it runs (in Chrome, with no complaints from Chrome's Javascript console) the final alert gives me my text string as expected, and then the alert in the onload function tells me it's been sent, also as expected.  But I get no server file called postTest.dat in the folder at the URL from which the HTML page containing the script was loaded into Chrome (or anywhere else on the server as far as a file search can tell).

Can someone please tell me how silly I am being?

Answer (score 0):

That makes a POST request to the server with whatever the return value of `NewFileToSave()` is as the body of the request. (Since the file doesn't exist already, you'll probably get a `404 Not Found` response).

If you want to create a file on the server, then you need the server to run a program that will read that data and use it to create a file (and you probably want to be using a PUT request instead of a POST request, to specify the `Content-Type` request header, and to add some kind of authentication/authorisation layer to the system).

The specifics of how you might go about that depend on which HTTP server you are using and your programming language preferences.

An arbitrary POST request to an arbitrary HTTP server won't create an arbitrary file. That would be a huge security hole.

Comment: Thanks!  I understand.  So the (relative) URL in the second argument of the open function is the file returned in response to the post (that may also do some messing about on the server before it returns some output)?  The documentation on this (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post) misses the one thing that one really needs to see: the file demo_post.asp to which it refers. I realise that this will be server-dependent, but an example there would still help...

Comment: "is the file returned in response to the post" — It is the URL to which the request is made. The server may map the URL onto a file system and use that to file a file with a matching name, it may not.

Comment: "misses the one thing that one really needs to see: the file demo_post.asp to which it refers" — You should probably treat learning basic server side programming as a prerequisite to learning how to use Ajax rather than something to learn about in parallel.

Comment: Then you'd be learning Classic ASP (which is a terrible choice as a first server side programming language this century) in the middle of learning Ajax instead of as a prerequisite.

Comment: Fair enough.  (I should perhaps say that I have written an entire - and amazing to me working and robust - web server in C++ for an ARM microcontroller before now from scratch.  It didn't do any asp-isms though, nor handle any posts because it didn't need to for the restricted application for which it was intended.)  Maybe I should re-read some of the documentation on that sort of thing, which I do have to say I don't find all that helpful as it seems to assume a level of knowledge a bit above where one is when one starts.

Comment: Don't get hung up on ASP. POST is basic HTTP 1.0 stuff. As I said, you need to treat server side programming as a prerequisite for Ajax (which is just a bit of glue to connect client side code to server side code).