# Can't post data to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a following problem while developing an AngularJS app.

I am trying to post some data into JSON file which I have Locally

when I am trying to do it I get this : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (17:52:25:265 | error, network)
  at public_html/logins.json

Here is a function which posts :

```
             $scope.sendOrder = function(shippingDetails){                 
             var order = angular.copy(shippingDetails);
             order.products = cart.getProducts();
             $http.post("orders.json",order)
                     .success(function(data){
                         $scope.data.orderId = data.id;
                         cart.getProducts().length =0;
                       })
                     .error(function(error){
                       $scope.data.orderError = error;  

                     })
                     .finally(function(){

                      $location.path("/complete");           
                     });

         };
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Posting to a static file? Seems weird

Comment: JSON is a data format, which does not run any code.  Are you trying to save data to the file?

Comment: you can not push data in a file like this, you need to edit your json file with a back-end language

Comment: Scott Kaye, yes I mean posting to JSON file.

Comment: you could use PUT if your server allows it, but most don't...

Comment: In that case, you'll have to set up a small server-side script in the language of your choosing to save the data.  Using PHP would make this as easy as [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).  I can write up an answer if that would help!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466858/xmlhttprequest-post-does-not-appear-as-file-on-server)

Comment: a json file is no different from a .txt file. You can't modify it with an ajax request alone, something has to receive the ajax request and do the work.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a format used to store data in a structured format, while POST is an HTTP protocol which is typically used to send data to a server.

To save your data to a file called orders.json, you'll have to create a server-side script that can has permission to interact with your filesystem.  Client-side code (like Javascript in the browser) can't do this, because it doesn't run on the server.

Here's some untested PHP code to take a value from `$_POST['data']` and save it to `orders.json`.  It is important to note that this will simply slap your data onto the end of the file, and will not keep structure.  It is *highly* advised to **use a database to store structured data**, rather than invent your own format and write APIs for it.

```
if($_POST['data'] && strlen($_POST['data']) > 0) {
    //This is super dangerous - saving user input directly to a file.
    //I'm not sure exactly what $_POST['data'] will contain for you, so please make sure it's sanitized before doing this
    file_put_contents("orders.json", $_POST['data'], FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

Then just call it with AJAX:

```
$http.post('filesaver.php', order)
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //do stuff
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //do different stuff
});
```